# Percentage above bars in histogram plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an histogram with percetages above the bars, this is my actual code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import random
Nombres_de_Pila = ["Alejandro", "Eric", "Mari", "Ruben", "Daniela", "Ana", "Ximena", "Ramón", "Diego",
                     "Fernanda", "José", "Lucia", "Alondra", "Saul", "Pilar", "Luis", "Victoria", "Lucas","Beatriz", "Elisa" ]
Apellidos = ["Martorell","Barroso","Galiano","Nava","Alcaraz","Peña","Varela","Romero","Rincón","Pineda",
              "Acuña","Pino","Arjona","Jimenez","Maroto","Carranza","Bosch","Costa","Godoy","Lopez"]
Eventos = random.choice(["11","12","21","22","31","32"], p=[0.1, 0.3,0.05,0.5,0.02,0.03], size = 1000)
Eventos = Eventos.tolist()
plt.hist(Eventos)
plt.xlabel('Número de nombres, Número de apellidos')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Histograma nombres generados\n\n',
        fontweight = "bold")
```

And this is the output:
[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6frxd.png)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I want to show the proportions of the bars above them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the duplicate.

```py
Nombres_de_Pila = ["Alejandro", "Eric", "Mari", "Ruben", "Daniela", "Ana", "Ximena", "Ramón", "Diego",
                     "Fernanda", "José", "Lucia", "Alondra", "Saul", "Pilar", "Luis", "Victoria", "Lucas","Beatriz", "Elisa" ]
Apellidos = ["Martorell","Barroso","Galiano","Nava","Alcaraz","Peña","Varela","Romero","Rincón","Pineda",
              "Acuña","Pino","Arjona","Jimenez","Maroto","Carranza","Bosch","Costa","Godoy","Lopez"]

np.random.seed(2023)
Eventos = np.random.choice(["11","12","21","22","31","32"], p=[0.1, 0.3,0.05,0.5,0.02,0.03], size = 1000)

plt.hist(Eventos)

# get the current axes and containers
c = plt.gca().containers[0]

# add the bar labels 
plt.bar_label(c, labels=[v.get_height()/len(Eventos) for v in c])
# plt.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: x/len(Eventos) if x > 0 else '')  # also works and doesn't annotate where the bar height is 0

# space between label and top of plot
plt.margins(y=0.1)

plt.xlabel('Número de nombres, Número de apellidos')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Histograma nombres generados\n\n', fontweight = "bold")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Id use this https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html set density=True in the plt.hist() as a kw argument.